# Can't connect to Docker Container on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, pgadmin

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: michael
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass123

  admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
```

I run `docker-compose up -d` and I can see my apps running from Docker Desktop. I cannot however connect to my `pgadmin` instance at port 5050 using `localhost`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker container of pgAdmin by default runs on port 80 as per the documentation here https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html

You are exposing port 5050 through the mapping. Either add a environment variable `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT` to the docker_compose to make pgAdmin run on port 5050

OR

change port mapping to `5050:80` for the pgAdmin service

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the `docker inspect` or `docker ps` results to ensure that you have your port exposed correctly
2. Try to connect to it using the public IP

Comment: I get "9fefead065c6 dpage/pgadmin4 "/entrypoint.sh" 38 minutes ago Up 34 minutes   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp" for the equivalent columns